# nodejs session storage

Tags: node.js, mongoose

In the connect-mongodb module we can store session in MongoDB like this:

```
var connect = require('connect')
, Db = require('mongodb').Db
, Server = require('mongodb').Server
, server_config = new Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true, native_parser: true})
, db = new Db('test', server_config, {})
, mongoStore = require('connect-mongodb');

connect.createServer(
  connect.bodyParser(),
  connect.cookieParser(),
  connect.session({
  cookie: {maxAge: 60000 * 20} // 20 minutes
  , secret: 'foo'
  , store: new mongoStore({db: db})
})
);
```

In the example above we have to use native mongodb stuff. In my nodejs project I use mongoose 2.4.1 so how should rewrite that code to use mongoose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mongoose and you used mongoose.connect, you can get the connection at

```
mongoose.connection
```

So to configure the session store you can use this form

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    mongoStore = require('connect-mongodb');
...
mongoose.connect(host,databaseName,port);
// mongoose.connect('mongodb://host:port/databaseName');
...

connect.session({
    secret: 'your secret key',
    cookie: { maxAge : 60*15*1000}, // 15 minutes, in milliseconds
    store: new mongoStore( { db : mongoose.connection.db })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no reason to do that, just use sessions with connect-mongodb which has all the 'Session Store' Express functionality implemented. Use Mongoose for everything else which requires db storage, but leave the sessions for connect-mongodb.

Here's a real example that does that: [https://github.com/alexyoung/nodepad](https://github.com/alexyoung/nodepad/blob/master/app.js)

Comment: I've tried this: store: MongoSessionStore('mongodb://localhost/test')
But it does not work

Comment: Look here, at line 88: https://github.com/alexyoung/nodepad/blob/master/app.js#L88

Comment: I use that. connect.createServer(
  connect.bodyParser(),
  connect.cookieParser(),
  connect.session({
  cookie: {maxAge: 60000 * 20} // 20 minutes
  , secret: 'foo'
  , store: new mongoStore({db: db})
})

Comment: Delete the 'new' word, leave -> store: mongoStore('mongodb://localhost/nodepad-test', secret: 'asdasd');

Comment: I've tried your example but I don't see database nodepad-development in MongoDB. Do you see that db?

Comment: Just pick a name, doesn't matter. It should be created and after you visit localhost:3000 you should see the session variable. More than that I don't know what to show you.

Comment: My steps is: 
1) Run mongodb in cmd: mongod.exe
2) create file server.js with content:

var connect = require('connect')
, Db = require('mongodb').Db
, Server = require('mongodb').Server
, server_config = new Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true, native_parser: true})
, db = new Db('test', server_config, {})
, mongoStore = require('connect-mongodb');

connect.createServer(
connect.bodyParser(),
connect.cookieParser(),
connect.session({
cookie: {maxAge: 60000 * 20} // 20 minutes
, secret: 'foo'
, store: new mongoStore({db: db})
})
);
3) i can see session in mongo

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose should expose the connection somehow.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `connect-mongo`, pass your mongoose connection like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);

new MongoStore({ mongoose_connection: mongoose.connection })
```

And everything will work as you'd expect.